# How do you display a 2 digit NumberPicker in android with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to use number pickers for my android app as a way to set a timer.
It works but I want to have 2 digits in the numbers 0-9 so instead of "0" it's "00" and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**%02d** You can format with. It will be filled in at least 2 digits.

```
// for java version

numberPicker.setFormatter(new NumberPicker.Formatter() {
            @Override
            public String format(int i) {
                return String.format("%02d", i);
            }
        });
```

Comment: That's great for java, and it looks like I might have to use java, but is there a way in Kotlin?

Comment: So the way to do it is essentially the same way: .setFormatter(
                fun(value: Int): String {
                    return String.format("%02d", value)
                }
        )

Answer (score 1):

```
private val formatter : NumberPicker.Formatter = NumberPicker.Formatter { String.format("%02d",it) }
minutePicker.setFormatter (formatter )
```

same code in kotlin

Answer (score 0):

## The [DecimalFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat) class is elegant and simple.

To format x in the style you want we simply put two digit indicators **#** next to each other. (Notice we use # instead of 0 in this case)

```
   val x = DecimalFormat("##")
```

| Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Digit |
| # | Digit, zero shows as absent |
| . | Decimal or monetary separator |
| - | Minus sign |
| , | Grouping separator |
| E | Separates mantissa , exponent |

------

```
**Java**
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class I18NTester {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String pattern = "####,####.##";
      double number = 123456789.123;
      System.out.println(number);
      System.out.println(numberFormat.format(number));
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! One other question. How would I use the val x? Would it be in numberPicker.setFormatter { }

Comment: you will need to learn what a program is, what the file structure is supposed to look like and what your end goal is. here is a tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/java/default.asp